# this.state.characters.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I know this a common question but I'm stuck in this situation and I think I know that my character is an object and it needs to be an array to properly function with `.map` but I don't know whats going wrong, if you guys can help me it would be awesome.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div class="ficha">
        <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        <h2>{this.props.species}</h2>
        <img src={this.props.image}></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      characters : []

    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    fetch("characters.json")
       .then(function(response) {
         return response.json();
    })
       .then(function(myJson) {
         self.setState({characters: myJson})


    });

  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.characters.map((ch, i) => 
      <Card key={i} name={ch.name} species={ch.species} image={ch.image}/>
     )}
    </div>
  );

      } 
    }



export default App;
```

This is my first post ever, and im fairly new with React, take it easy please :D
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if data has been stored properly in the State?

Comment: Is `myJson` an array?

Comment: @AnglesvarCheenu it doesnt, its undefined

Comment: `fetch("characters.json")
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(myJson => {this.setState({characters: myJson})})`

This might help you store data in the state and please donot use a variable to store a pre-defined keyword, this could end up in a confusion when you post it in a community.

Comment: @Monala92 since this Initial state is an empty array, that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fat-arrow function so that `this` is correctly inferred, instead of using var to store the `this` reference:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch("characters.json")
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(myJson => {this.setState({characters: myJson})})
    });
```

Now as long as `myJson` is actually the correct json, it should work.

Comment: I tried that and it doesnt work, maybe myjson is an object and map only works with arrays, but i defined and empty array for my characters in the constructor :S

Comment: Can you console log your response from the fetch?